# Let $φ : G → G_0$ be a group homomorphism. Show that if |G| is ﬁnite, then $|φ[G]|$ is ﬁnite and is a divisor of |G|.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: Let $φ : G → G_0$ be a group homomorphism. Show that if |G| is ﬁnite,
then $|φ[G]|$ is ﬁnite and is a divisor of |G|.
φ[G] is the image of a subset under its domain.

A: φ[G] = {φ(g): g $\in$ G} so |φ[G]| $\leq$ |G| (Would these be equal if φ[G] was the image of its domain instead of a subset?).

...

I'm not sure how to answer the second part of the question. I saw the solution & it uses a kernel but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the first isomorphism theorem? (Or is this perhaps an exercise as part of proving the first isomorphism theorem?)

Comment: I know we have used it in class before to show 2 groups are isomorphic to one another. I definitely need to review it before my exam next week.

Comment: Ok. Then as a hint, try applying the first isomorphism theorem. We know that $G/\ker(\varphi) \cong im(\varphi)$. Now use the fact that $\ker(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Okay thank you for the hint! It helped a lot knowing to use that theorem! 
I was able to get it without Ben's answer the same way he did but it's nice seeing his answer written neatly!

Comment: However you said use the fact that ker(φ) is a subgroup of G, how did we have to use that in Brett's answer?

Comment: Adam: we didn't, really. I didn't think to remove it until after editing my comment had expired. :) Hope it helped anyway though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem, you have $G/\ker(\varphi)\simeq\varphi[G]$. Since your group is finite, this just means
$$
|\varphi[G]|=[G:\ker(\varphi)]=|G|/|\ker(\varphi)|.
$$
Rearranging, since every cardinality is just an integer,
$$
|\ker(\varphi)|=\frac{|G|}{|\varphi[G]|}.
$$
So $|\varphi[G]|$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: How can I prove it if I have not seen the first isomorphism theorem?